# Finding the largest prime factor

Tags: c++, primes

I was working on the following problem from Project Euler.

`What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?`

I have come up with the following solution.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>
 /**Project Euler:What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143**/
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int n){
    int sq,a=2;
    sq=sqrt(n);
    while(a<sq)
    {
        if(n%a==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main() {
int c=2,max_prime;
long long d=600851475143;
int e=sqrt(d);
while(c<e)
{
    if(isPrime(c))
    {
            if(d%c==0)
                max_prime=c;
    }
c++;
}
cout<<max_prime;
    return 0;
}
```

There is no compilation error in the program but it is taking a lot of time in running. I have looked at other solutions but am not able to find out the mistake in my solution.I suspect there is something wrong because of the large number involved. What could that be? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your isPrime function never increments `a`, so you're in an endless loop there.

Comment: Thanks. It Worked. Btw is there a more efficient way to solve the same problem?

Comment: Sure. I'd start with sqrt(d) and work downwards, and `break` the loop as soon as i hit a solution (check if the solution is prime however!). Also, handling the case '2' separately, then start loops with 3 and increment by 2 halfes execution time - there's no need to test 4, 6, 8, ... if 2 doesn't work. And last, but very important - the isPrime(c) check in your main() is a BIG time killer. The `d % c == 0` check is much faster than the `isPrime()` check, so better check `d % c == 0` first and only call isPrime if the mod check is true. Oh, and indent your code properly!

Comment: Counting down from the square root will solve this particular example (albeit not very efficiently), but in general consider examples like `2*3*11 = 66`. The largest prime factor is `11`, the square root is `8`, so you won't find the `11` until you get down to `2`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's optimal, but my first attempt for this is just to completely factorize the number: search upwards with trial division; when you find a factor divide it out of `d`; stop when you reach the square root of whatever is left in `d`. Because it's an early Project Euler problem, the number they chose is pretty friendly and so that works rather well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your `isPrime` method you're not changing any of the variables that control the `while` condition within the body of the `while` statement, so the loop wil run forever.